# How to merge multiple YouTube videos into one

Tags: video, merge, youtube-api

Is it possible to join/merge (one after the other) multiple YT videos I have already uploaded into one (using their API preferable)?

Due to limited resources of the available computer, doing video encoding (using ffmpeg etc.) to do the merge before upload isn't possible. If it matters, I care only for video tracks, so ignore audio.

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Creating an overlay of one video on top of another? Or kind of multiplexing two video tracks to a single container?

Comment: Multiplexing, concatenating, adding each track after the other sequentially. Currently I can do this on YouTube's Video Editor manually, but I need it done programatically.

Comment: in what language are you interested in? did you search for libraries in that language?

Comment: I'm using a python lib at the moment https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload but anything that can run on Raspberry will do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this isn't possible with Google's official APIs. See their documentation here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/

the youtube.videos.update endpoint is only able to edit the metadata, which unfortunately doesn't include merging videos.

There might be an alternative, simulating a real user accessing the website. I'll look at it when I get home from work.

Comment: I thought about "simulating" a user to do it via the video editor, but issues will arise and I was hoping that I missed some other clean solution.

Comment: I'm afraid not, I haven't actually had a chance to look at it yet. But I am expecting that it won't be as simple. It is possible to do a manual merge on a RPi, it would just take time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it by go to your CREATOR STUDIO then under CREATE tab select VIDEO EDITOR. [Youtube screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcitr.png)
In editor, your can add and merge existing (uploaded by you) videos into one.

Comment: That is the way I found also, but I need an automated way, thus I thought of the API.

Comment: I'm looking for the same. I was thinking, we can automate these simple bunch of clicks using a bot :)

Comment: [As of September 20, 2017, Video Editor is no longer available](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/183851?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, but there is a workaround. If you still have the videos files, you could merge them with an editor and re-upload, then deleting the other videos. This is a working solution, but sadly it would take a extremely long time.
The shorter way would be to merge them after upload, but according the Google's API's this frankly isn't possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, like I mentioned before doing the merge on my part isn't fitting for my case, because it's a resource-heavy operation.